# Attribute error for class object in Python - Naive Bayes

Tags: python, class, attributeerror, naivebayes

I'm trying to make a Naive Bayes Classifier from scratch for spam filtration in Python.  When I try to train the class, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/francescacape/Desktop/testnb.py", line 97, in <module>
    nb.train(traindata)
  File "/Users/francescacape/Desktop/testnb.py", line 36, in train
    self._hamdocs += 1
AttributeError: 'NLPNaiveBayes' object has no attribute '_hamdocs'
```

I'm new to programming and this is the first Class I've built.  I can't figure out why this is happening because the attribute is defined under the constructor.  Apologies, my code is a bit long.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import math
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import glob



class NLPNaiveBayes:

    def _init__(self):
        self._spamdocs = 0
        self._hamdocs = 0
        self.totaldocs = self._spamdocs + self._hamdocs
        self.spamwordcount = defaultdict(int)
        self.hamwordcount = defaultdict(int)
        self.spamwords = {}
        self.hamwords = {}
        self.totalwords = set()
        self.totalspamwords = []
        self.totalhamwords = []
        self.priorlogham = math.log(self._hamdocs / self.totaldocs)
        self.priorlogspam = math.log(self._spamdocs / self.totaldocs)

    @staticmethod
    def preprocessing(message):
        toks = list(word_tokenize(message))
        words = [word.islower() for word in toks if word.isalnum()]
        return set(words)

    def train(self, data):
        for message, cat in data:
            if is_spam:
                self._spamdocs += 1
                self.totalspamwords.append(message)
            else:
                self._hamdocs += 1
                self.totalhamwords.append(message)
            words = self.preprocessing(message)
            for word in words:
                if is_spam:
                    self.totalwords.update(word)
                    self.spamwords.update(word)
                    self.spamwordcount[word] += 1
                else:
                    self.totalwords.update(word)
                    self.hamwords.update(word)
                    self.hamwordcount[word] += 1

        for word, count in self.totalspamwords.item():
            self.spamwords[word] = math.log((int(count) + 1)) / (self._spamdocs + self.totaldocs)
        for word, count in self.totalhamwords.item():
            self.hamwords[word] = math.log((int(count) + 1)) / (self._hamdocs + self.totaldocs)


nb = NLPNaiveBayes()
nb.train(traindata)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is an exact copy of your code, then I think your init method has the incorrect name - it should `__init__` - two underscores before and after. you appear to only have one underscore before and two after (`_init__`).

Because the name is wrong, it means it wont be executed when the instance is constructed.